# Can I make a multi-color line in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a colored line with certain conditions. Basically I would like to have the line colored red when pointing down on the y axis, green when pointing up and blue when neither.

I played around with some similar examples I found but I have never been able to convert them to work with plot() on an axis. Just wondering how this could be done.

Here is some code that I have come up with so far:

```
#create x,y coordinates
x = numpy.random.choice(10,10)
y = numpy.random.choice(10,10)

#create an array of colors based on direction of line (0=r, 1=g, 2=b)
colors = []
#create an array that is one position away from original 
#to determine direction of line 
yCopy = list(y[1:])
for y1,y2 in zip(y,yCopy):
    if y1 > y2:
        colors.append(0)
    elif y1 < y2:
        colors.append(1)
    else:
        colors.append(2)
#add tenth spot to array as loop only does nine
colors.append(2)

#create a numpy array of colors
categories = numpy.array(colors)

#create a color map with the three colors
colormap = numpy.array([matplotlib.colors.colorConverter.to_rgb('r'),matplotlib.colors.colorConverter.to_rgb('g'),matplotlib.colors.colorConverter.to_rgb('b')])

#plot line
matplotlib.axes.plot(x,y,color=colormap[categories])
```

Not sure how to get plot() to accept an array of colors. I always get an error about the format type used as the color. Tried heximal, decimal, string and float. Works perfect with scatter().

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think that you can use an array of colors in `plot` (the documentation says that color can be any matlab color, while the `scatter` docs say you can use an array).

However, you could fake it by plotting each line separately:

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = range(10)
y = numpy.random.choice(10,10)
for x1, x2, y1,y2 in zip(x, x[1:], y, y[1:]):
    if y1 > y2:
        plt.plot([x1, x2], [y1, y2], 'r')
    elif y1 < y2:
        plt.plot([x1, x2], [y1, y2], 'g')
    else:
        plt.plot([x1, x2], [y1, y2], 'b')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: lol.  That was going to be my next attempt. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Actually it can be done with LineCollection but I don't understand how to adapt it to my needs.

Answer (score 9):

OK.  So I figured out how to do it using LineCollecion to draw the line on a axis.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
from matplotlib import collections  as mc

segments = []
colors = np.zeros(shape=(10,4))
x = range(10)
y = np.random.choice(10,10)
i = 0

for x1, x2, y1,y2 in zip(x, x[1:], y, y[1:]):
    if y1 > y2:
        colors[i] = tuple([1,0,0,1])
    elif y1 < y2:
        colors[i] = tuple([0,1,0,1])
    else:
        colors[i] = tuple([0,0,1,1])
    segments.append([(x1, y1), (x2, y2)])
    i += 1     

lc = mc.LineCollection(segments, colors=colors, linewidths=2)
fig, ax = pl.subplots()
ax.add_collection(lc)
ax.autoscale()
ax.margins(0.1)
pl.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is an [example on the matplotlib page](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html) showing how to use a `LineCollection` to plot a multicolored line.

The remaining problem is to get the colors for the line collection. So if `y` are the values to compare,

```
cm = dict(zip(range(-1,2,1),list("gbr")))
colors = list( map( cm.get , np.sign(np.diff(y))  ))
```

Complete code:

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(5)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.random.choice(10,10)

points = np.array([x, y]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)

cm = dict(zip(range(-1,2,1),list("rbg")))
colors = list( map( cm.get , np.sign(np.diff(y))  ))

lc = LineCollection(segments, colors=colors, linewidths=2)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_collection(lc)

ax.autoscale()
ax.margins(0.1)
plt.show()
```

[image]