# How to plot two list in the same graph, with different colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, line-plot

I need to plot two lists on the same graph. The lines should be of different colors.

I am trying to plot `forecast` and `train_Z` on the same graph, but I get them plotted against each other, with `forecast` on the x-axis, and `train_Z` on the y-axis.

Here is the code I tried:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

train_X = [1,2,3,4,5] 
train_Y = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50] 
train_Z = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50,25] 
alpha = float(input("Input alpha: ")) 
forecast = []

for x in range(0, len(train_X)+1):  
    if x==0:       
        forecast.append(train_Y[0])  
    else:  
        forecast.append(alpha*train_Y[x-1] + (1 - alpha) * forecast[x-1])
plt.plot(forecast,train_Z,'g') 
plt.show()
```

With `alpha == 5`

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You should use `plt.plot` twice to plot two lines.

I don't know what is your X axis but obviously you should create another array/list to be your X value.

Then use `plt.plot(x_value,forecast, c='color-you-want')`
and `plt.plot(x_value,train_z, c='another-color-you-want')`.

. Please refer to the [pyplot](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html) documentation for more details.

Answer (score 9):

As per the [`matplotlib.pyplot.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html), plot multiple sets with `[x], y, [fmt]`. If `y` is passed without a corresponding `x`, then `y` will be plotted sequentially against `range(len(y))`.

#### Scatter Plot

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y1 = [1,2,3,4,12,15]
y2 = [1,4,9,16]

plt.plot(y1, 'g*', y2, 'ro')
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Line Plot

```py
plt.plot(y1, 'g', y2, 'r')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

<s>Stealing</s> Borrowing from another answer, this appears to work:

```
# plt.plot(forecast,train_Z,'g') # replace this line, with the following for loop

for x1, x2, y1,y2 in zip(forecast, forecast[1:], train_Z, train_Z[1:]):
    if y1 > y2:
        plt.plot([x1, x2], [y1, y2], 'r')
    elif y1 < y2:
        plt.plot([x1, x2], [y1, y2], 'g')
    else:
        plt.plot([x1, x2], [y1, y2], 'b') # only visible if slope is zero

plt.show()
```

[image]

other answer: [python/matplotlib - multicolor line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35394078/1248974)

Of course, replace the `'r'`, `'g'`, `'b'` values with any others in https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot colors list

Answer (score -2):

```
plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1])
plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]) #these combination in plot one
plt.title("First plot")


plt.figure()

plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1])
plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])# it is plotted in second plot
plt.title("second plot")
```

Comment: now they are just with different input you may check now

Comment: I'm voting to delete this because it's the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45155676/7758804). Don't add **thank you**, or **confirmation** answers. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) from quality contributions, you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) you found helpful.

Comment: It's the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45155676/7758804) with lists substituted for the variable names.