# Spaghetti plot without a for loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

I want to make a spaghetti plot (lots of lines in one window) using `matplotlib.pyplot`. Different lines need to be different colors based on my data. However, I do not want to use a for loop for each line because I need it to work fast. I'm using matplotlib event handling and replotting over 200 lines based on mouse drag; a for loop takes too long for that.

While there isn't any documentation on this I found out that if you use `plt.plot` and pass on an array for x and a matrix for y it prints out multiple lines. And it's super fast. However all of them have to be the same color. And passing on an array for color results in an error.

```py
_ = plt.plot([0,1,2,3,4], np.matrix.transpose(np.asarray([[0,0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2,2]])), color='blue', linewidth=1, alpha=0.4)
```

This code produces 3 horizontal lines in one plot and takes faster than using the plot command 3 times. This is great, but i want different colors. If i do

```
_ = plt.plot([0,1,2,3,4], np.matrix.transpose(np.asarray([[0,0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2,2]])), color=['blue', 'red, 'green'], linewidth=1, alpha=0.4)
```

I get an error `Invalid RGBA argument: array(['blue', 'red', 'red'], dtype='<U4')`

Comment: remove the color arg

Comment: For an efficiency comparison for drawing many lines, see [Many plots in less time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54492963/many-plots-in-less-time-python). An implementation of a `LineCollection` with several colors would be shown in [python/matplotlib - multicolor line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46348309/4124317).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Remove the color argument, and it'll happen automatically

```
a = [0,0,0,0,0]
b = [1,1,1,1,1]
c = [2,2,2,2,2]

plt.plot([0,1,2,3,4], np.matrix.transpose(np.asarray([a, b, c])), linewidth=1, alpha=0.4)
```

[image]

#### If you just want colored horizontal lines:

```
plt.hlines([0, 1, 2], 0, 4, ['r', 'b', 'g'])
```

[image]

#### Use seaborn:

- seaborn is a high-level api for matplotlib.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

ex = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 0, 0],
                   'b': [1, 1, 1],
                   'c': [2, 2, 2]})

# either palette works
palette=["#9b59b6", "#3498db", "#95a5a6"]
# palette=['blue', 'red', 'green']

sns.lineplot(data=ex, palette=palette, dashes=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Additional options:

- [PyViz: Python data visualization landscape](https://pyviz.org/index.html)
- [Line Collection from matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/shapes_and_collections/line_collection.html)
- As pointed out by [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest)
- [Many plots in less time - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54492963/many-plots-in-less-time-python)
- [python/matplotlib - multicolor line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372993/python-matplotlib-multicolor-line/46348309#46348309)