# How do I plot a line with x and y and transparency data taken from an array?

Tags: arrays, matplotlib, transparency

I'm very much a python beginner trying to adapt someone else's code.

I have an array in which the first column is the x data, 2nd column is y data and the 3rd column contains values between 0 and 1 which I'd like to represent the transparency of the line. In other words the transparency of the line changes according to the data in the array.

Any ideas how I could do this?

I've tried this which works to plot the data in array Bb if I remove the alpha command or set it to fixed value, but doesn't work in this form.

```
    ax.plot(Bb[:, 0], Bb[:, 1], 'r', alpha=Bb[:, 2])
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

Comment: Can you post some code you have tried and data you are using?

Comment: Use a `LineCollection`.

Comment: I've added the code I've tried in the original post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python/matplotlib - multicolor line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372993/python-matplotlib-multicolor-line)